# How to write query in Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

So my manager wants me to send 3 types of log data to `Kibana`.

1. System Logs
2. Trace Logs
3. Audit Logs

So below the flow I followed:

```
App Logs (all 3) -> AWSLog Driver -> Cloud Watch Logs -> Elastic Search Cluster -> Kibana
```

The logs are in JSON Format. So I am able to create a basic dashboard and all. But can I query it? Suppose I want to get a Audit Log with `id = 123`. How can I query that data and see it. Please guide me.

Do we have SQL Server like query capabilities in AWS ES Cluster?

Comment: Were you able to login to kibana? Goto DevTools and then write your queries there. Take a look at the [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html)

Comment: or you can see in your dashboard query for each visualization and it’s results in JSON format